# Citrix does not show persian tooltips properly when the client os is windows7

Tags: windows-7, citrix

I use Citrix to publish a windows-based application on the Internet.
It seems Citrix has a problem to show the persian tooltips properly when client OS is Windows7 ,there is no problem when the client OS is Windows XP.
what can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: I have no idea the problem is related to which one: Windows7 or Citrix!

Answer (score 0):

Try to troubleshoot if this a seamless app problem [using the Citrix Checklist](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX138775).

And if it is, then try to find the right seamless compatibility flag [with FarmTWIHelper](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115146).